# WIX - Adding a custom Dialog having trouble with back/next buttons

Tags: wix

I am working on creating a custom WixUi configuration, here is what I've done so far:

Copied the WixUI_Minimal.wxs file into my project and changed the Id to: WixUI_CustomMinimal
Copied the WelcomeEulaDlg.wxs file into my project and changed the Id to: CustomWelcomeEulaDlg
Copied the WelcomeDlg.wxs file into my project and changed the Id to: CustomWelcomeDlg
Added InstallTypeDlg.wxs to my project

Modified the CustomWelcomeEulaDlg to change the Install button to a next button.
Modified WixUI_CustomMinimal to make the Next/NextNoShield buttons on WelcomeEulaDlg open the InstallTypeDlg dialog

Added the InstallTypeDlg Dialog to the InstallUiSequence.

So now the problem: I am trying to setup a back button on InstallTypeDlg, this is working but after pressing the back button and then pressing the next button on CustomWelcomeEulaDlg InstallTypeDlg is skipped and it goes straight to installing.

Here are my files:

WixUI_CustomMinimal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  <copyright file="WixUI_Minimal.wxs" company="Outercurve Foundation">
    Copyright (c) 2004, Outercurve Foundation.
    This software is released under Microsoft Reciprocal License (MS-RL).
    The license and further copyright text can be found in the file
    LICENSE.TXT at the root directory of the distribution.
  </copyright>
-->

<!--
First-time install dialog sequence:
 - WixUI_WelcomeEulaDlg

Maintenance dialog sequence:
 WixUI_MaintenanceWelcomeDlg
 - WixUI_MaintenanceTypeDlg
 - WixUI_VerifyReadyDlg

Patch dialog sequence:
 - WixUI_WelcomeDlg
 - WixUI_VerifyReadyDlg
-->

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI Id="WixUI_CustomMinimal">
          <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

            <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
            <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Minimal" />

            <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
            <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
            <DialogRef Id="CustomWelcomeDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="InstallTypeDlg" />


            <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="CustomWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomWelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallTypeDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" Control="NextNoShield" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallTypeDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="InstallTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

            <InstallUISequence>
                <Show Dialog="CustomWelcomeDlg" Before="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Show>
                <Show Dialog="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" Before="InstallTypeDlg">NOT Installed</Show>
                <Show Dialog="InstallTypeDlg" Before="ProgressDlg">NOT Installed</Show>
            </InstallUISequence>

            <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
        </UI>

        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

CustomWelcomeEulaDlg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  <copyright file="WelcomeEulaDlg.wxs" company="Outercurve Foundation">
    Copyright (c) 2004, Outercurve Foundation.
    This software is released under Microsoft Reciprocal License (MS-RL).
    The license and further copyright text can be found in the file
    LICENSE.TXT at the root directory of the distribution.
  </copyright>
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.WelcomeEulaDlg_Title)">
                <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeEulaDlgBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="130" Y="6" Width="225" Height="30" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.WelcomeEulaDlgTitle)" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="LicenseAcceptedCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="130" Y="207" Width="226" Height="18" CheckBoxValue="1" Property="LicenseAccepted" Text="!(loc.WelcomeEulaDlgLicenseAcceptedCheckBox)" />
                <Control Id="Print" Type="PushButton" X="88" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIPrint)">
                    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIPrintEula">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next" Hidden="yes">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>

                    <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[LicenseAccepted <> "1"]]></Condition>
                    <Condition Action="enable">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="show">ALLUSERS</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="NextNoShield" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next" Hidden="yes">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>

                    <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[LicenseAccepted <> "1"]]></Condition>
                    <Condition Action="enable">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="show">NOT ALLUSERS</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="LicenseText" Type="ScrollableText" X="130" Y="36" Width="226" Height="162" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no">
                    <Text SourceFile="!(wix.WixUILicenseRtf)" />
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>

        <InstallUISequence>
            <Show Dialog="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" Before="ProgressDlg" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed</Show>
        </InstallUISequence>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

InstallTypeDlg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  <copyright file="WelcomeEulaDlg.wxs" company="Outercurve Foundation">
    Copyright (c) 2004, Outercurve Foundation.
    This software is released under Microsoft Reciprocal License (MS-RL).
    The license and further copyright text can be found in the file
    LICENSE.TXT at the root directory of the distribution.
  </copyright>
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
          <Property Id="INSTALLTYPE" Value="Null"/>
            <Dialog Id="InstallTypeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.WelcomeEulaDlg_Title)">

                <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeEulaDlgBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="130" Y="6" Width="225" Height="30" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.WelcomeEulaDlgTitle)" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="Print" Type="PushButton" X="88" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIPrint)">
                    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIPrintEula">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install" Hidden="yes">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="AddLocal" Value="ServiceFeature"><![CDATA[INSTALLTYPE = "SERVICE"]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="Remove" Value="ServiceFeature"><![CDATA[INSTALLTYPE <> "SERVICE"]]></Publish>
                    <Condition Action="disable">INSTALLTYPE = "Null"</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[INSTALLTYPE <> "Null"]]></Condition>
                    <Condition Action="show">ALLUSERS</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="InstallNoShield" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install" Hidden="yes">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="AddLocal" Value="ServiceFeature"><![CDATA[INSTALLTYPE = "SERVICE"]]></Publish>
                    <Publish Event="Remove" Value="ServiceFeature"><![CDATA[INSTALLTYPE <> "SERVICE"]]></Publish> 
                    <Condition Action="disable">INSTALLTYPE = "Null"</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[INSTALLTYPE <> "Null"]]></Condition>
                    <Condition Action="show">NOT ALLUSERS</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="FeatureGroup" Property="INSTALLTYPE" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Default="no" X="130" Y="36" Width="226" Height="162">
                  <RadioButtonGroup Property="INSTALLTYPE">
                    <RadioButton Text="Console" Height="17" Value="CONSOLE" Width="150" X="20" Y="0" />
                    <RadioButton Text="Windows Service" Height="17" Value="SERVICE" Width="150" X="20" Y="25" />
                    <RadioButton Value="Null" X="0" Y="0" Width="0" Height="0" Text="Null" />
                  </RadioButtonGroup>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>

        <InstallUISequence>
            <Show Dialog="InstallTypeDlg" Before="ProgressDlg" Overridable="yes">NOT Installed</Show>
        </InstallUISequence>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is in the `InstallUISequence`. You should use:

```xml
<Show Dialog="CustomWelcomeDlg" Before="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg">
    Installed AND PATCH
</Show>
<Show Dialog="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" Before="ProgressDlg">
    NOT Installed
</Show>
```

In the CustomWelcomeEulaDlg, the Back and Next buttons should be like this:

```
<Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="243"
         Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="Back" />

<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes"
         X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes"
         Text="Next" Hidden="yes">
    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallTypeDlg">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

And in the InstallTypeDlg, the Back and Install buttons should be similar to this:

```
<Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="243" Width="56"
         Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="Back">
    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg">1</Publish>
</Control>

<Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243"
         Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install" Hidden="yes">
    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
</Control>
```